# How to handle DB ddl/migrations with cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, database-migration, aws-cloudformation, ddl

I am building a project using Lambdas, SNS, and a MySql. The project is deployed using CloudFormation. I initially started with DynamoDB but realized that my data is actually relational and there is not a ton of data so using a RDS would be better for my situation. I am having a hard time finding information online about how database migrations are handled within CloudFormation.

What is the proper way to handle these migrations? I found information on using lambda to do the [migrations](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/06/database-migration-aws-lambda/). Is that the best way?